# Matrices problem with determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $a,b$ be complex non-zero numbers such that $a^2 \ne b$ and $a^2 \ne 4b$. Let $A,B$ be $3 \times 3$ matrices with complex elements such that $A^2-aAB+bB^2=\text O_3.$ Show that $$\det(pAB+qBA)=(p+q)^3\det(AB),$$ for every complex numbers $p$ and $q$.

Comment: You must share your work and thoughts.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: What are $p$ and $q$?